# Undefined values returned by JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, getjson

According to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794967/how-to-store-json-data-into-javascript-table-format) I am trying to get back some information from a RESTful interface using JSON. I am working on JQuery 1.5.

The problem I face is that I get back as a result **undefined values**. I am not able to use firebug because my application is developed using PhoneGap and the app is running on the iPhone's simulator.

If I visit the RESTful interface (I type the "example.json" url in a browser - where example is a valid url created by another developer) returns me results with the following format:

```
[{"person":{"created_at":"2011-07-18T17:51:33Z","id":1,"name":"John","age":60,"surname":"Smith","car_id":1,"updated_at":"2011-07-18T17:51:33Z"}},{"person":{"created_at":"2011-07-18T17:51:35Z","id":1,"name":"Johnny","age":50,"surname":"Deep","car_id":2,"updated_at":"2011-07-18T17:51:35Z"}}]
```

I need to get the information id, name, age and store them in an array (not an html table). Just to see if the connection returns any values I use the code:

```
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function(person) {
        $.each(person, function(i, person) {
            alert(person.name);
            alert(person.age);
        });
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("Cannot connect to the SWT's maps. Please try again later!"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

**So, why do I get by the alert undefined as values?**

Comment: Are you editing your question ?

Comment: @Christophe yes, I had typing errors, now this is exactly how my code looks like.

Comment: @ChristopheCVB yes, the code Fabrizio suggested is working and I get the name and the age of both persons from the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function(person) {
        $.each(person, function(i, item) {
            alert(item.person.name);
            alert(item.person.age);
        });
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("Cannot connect to the SWT's maps. Please try again later!"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: @ Fabrizio thank you very very much! Indeed it is now working! I need one more thing though if you can help me with this as well, how can I store the values now (I will not know the number of returned values) in an array?

Comment: My suggestion is to declare an array and populate in the $.each loop. You don't need to know the number of returned "person" records.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure of your code ? try:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("example.json", function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        alert(item.name);
        alert(item.age);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's not quite right either. I think it would have to be item['person'].name

Comment: Sorry that was a type mistake, I corrected the code now, I have person, not data. I also tried the code by @wezzy but still not working...vPlease help me, it is urgent to finish it.

Comment: @CiscolPPhone i haven't tried but where's the error ? it looks the same of yours in the answer below

Comment: @tesanoui you still get the error ? try with console.log(person), what you get ?

Comment: @wezzy I still get undefined values. I do not know how to use the console.log(person) with PhoneGap. I am running my application on an iPhone simulator. If you know, can you please let me know?